# get Key->Value in json Array in Google apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

In Google Apps Script I am getting an array of JSON objects.  If I want to access the key value pair of "id: value" could I simple do the following?

```
 var id = myArrayofJson[0].id;
```

I would use jQuery but it's not allowed in the Google Api.

Comment: JSON is a string that is easily deserializable into *JavaScript* objects.  Do you have an array of JSON strings or JavaScript objects?

Comment: I figured it out.  And yes it was an array of json objects.  I just needed to use:
      myArrayofJson[i][someId][someOtherId].....
Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON Object" there are "JSON strings" and "JavaScript objects".  The difference is *not* trivial.

Answer (score 0):

what I had was an array of json objects so the answer for my question was:

```
for(i=0; i < myArray.length; i++){
  var receive = myArray[i][jsonId][anotherId];
 }
```

I just didn't know how to use json arrays properly but got the help from you and others.  thank you.